# Issue with copying data from s3 to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to sync a table from MySQL RDS to redshift trough data pipeline.
There was no issue in copying data frm RDS to S3. But while copying S3 to redhsift the follwoing isue is seen.

```
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load data: Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]
```

While observing data it is seen that while copying data to S3 an extra "0" is being appended at the end of time stamp i.e 2015-04-28 10:25:58 from MySQL table is being copied as 2015-04-28 10:25:58.0 into CSV file which is giving issue.

I also tried copying with copy command using the following

```
copy XXX
from 's3://XXX/rds//2018-02-27-14-38-04/1d6d39b9-4aac-408d-8275-3131490d617d.csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/XXX' delimiter ',' timeformat 'auto';
```

but still the same issue.

Can anyone help me sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to solve this extra 0 problem? Not sure from why it appends .0 at the end.